# Foreach input php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I know there are similar topics out there but haven't been able to find what I'm looking for. So what I need to do is target a specific input name and foreach loop only that input instead of the whole form.

HTML look something like below.

```
        <form action"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="table1" method="post">
            <input name="something1" type="text" />
            <input name="something2" type="text" /> 
            <input name="something3" type="text" />
            <input name="something4" type="text" />
            <input name="something4" type="text" />
            <input name="something4" type="text" /> 
            <input name="button"  type="submit" value="Add" />    
        </form>
```

So I wanna loop every "something4" and just ignore the rest. Is this possible?

Just to explain what I want to do with the value is for every "something4" I'm gonna add a field to my DB and the input the respective input value into that field.

something like below...

```
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($_POST as $something4 => $something4_value) {
            $add = mysqli_query($connect, "ALTER TABLE 'table' ADD something4$i VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL") or die (mysql_error());
            $sql_update = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE 'table' SET something4$i='$something_value' WHERE id='$id'") or die (mysql_error());
            $i++;
        }
```

I hope this make sense! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create each of the `name="something4"` into an array like this:

```
<input name="something4[]" type="text" />
```

Then you can do a

```
foreach($_POST['something4'] as $something4) {
}
```

Comment: So simple, so beautiful! Thanks alot!

Comment: Do you mind if I ask you another question around this topic with foreach loops?

Comment: Of course. Although it may be best to simply post a new question.

Comment: I will but you seemed to have a good grip around this foreach topic and i'm pretty new to it. I got it to work so it now count the number to put in database and it's values. But now I need to grab ta info on a new page. I tried something like this.

foreach ($row['something[$i]'] as $values){
    $value .= $values;
    $i++;
   }
But that din't seem to do it. If I do $row['something0'] I get the first row tho.

Comment: It all depends on how you are building the `$row` array. If it's from the results of a `mysqli_query`, then your structure will depend on the query. This isn't a suitable place to discuss this, so you should start a new question.