# Gather column and rows with MySqli and foreach loop

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

So I'm pretty new to foreach loops and don't seem to be able to get the hang of this one thing. I want to pull an unknown amount of columns from my db called "something1", "something2", etc.. and with each column I want to get the data from each row. something like this "something1: Apple, Pear, Grape" and then the same for the next column.

I upload and count the number of rows and columns with a foreach loop found on link below:
[Foreach input php and mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007558/foreach-input-php-and-mysql/31007613?noredirect=1#comment50085144_31007613)

I have tried a few things like this

```
//Grabing DB above.
$Count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if($Count > 0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $i = 0;
    if ($type == "somethingrows"){
        foreach ($row['something$i'] as $values){
            $something_value = $values;
            $i++;
        }
$output .= "<option value='$something_value'>$something_value</option>";
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas or thoughts are very welcome!
Thanks!

Comment: What is your problem exactly? I got to little information. but I see some problems. 1. change `$row['something$i']` to `$record['something' . $i]`. 2. I miss 3 closing curly brackets "}". 3. $something_value is getting only the value of the last foreach loop, it is getting overwritten every loop.

Comment: 1. Tried this but that gave me a error.  2. Sorry, forgot to copy them! 3. put this up within the foreach loop and added $out = "<select name='somethings'>$output</select>"; out side the loop instead. Still same issue :/. Basically what I want to do is grab all rows from a column called "optionXX" and then in the page be able by a select function choose between all the row values within that "optionXX". Hope that clears it out a little!

Comment: If I get it right you want to make a page with a form and this form must contain checkboxes for every row? So you can check or uncheck them to get only those entire rows?

Comment: exactly I got a  form with a select option (drop down not checkboxes). Where I want to output all my rows so I can select one.

Comment: drop down, so you want to select 1 option?

Comment: exactly, but all options need to be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first pplace,

## You should never have an unknown amount of columns called "something1", "something2" in your db.

That's violation of the very basic principle of database architecture.

Instead, you should have a **separate table**, where all these unknown colums have to be stored, in the form of rows, linked to the other table by unique identifier. So, the new table should be looking like this:

```
other table id | something
1              | foo
1              | bar
2              | foo
1              | baz
```

You can select your somethings via separate query and then process them in a usual loop without any complications.

## That's the ONLY way to go.

and that's the only right answer to this kind of questions.

Comment: Yep, re-did the whole thing and worked around this idea instead got it to work like a charm in first try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. you need to change some setting.

1. Change connection data to your information $host, $user, $pass, $dbdb
2. Maybe you need to change table and field name, both queries.
3. Change test.php to the name of your file.

---

test.php:

```
//Use your connection data here
$user = "";
$pass = "";
$host = "";
$dbdb = "";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbdb);
if(!$connect)
{
    trigger_error('Error connection to database: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}

//select column optionXX from table, maybe you need to change the column-name or/and table-name
$sql = "SELECT `optionXX` FROM `table`";
$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

//put all records we have selected in an array to be used later in the HTML
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $optionsArray[] = $record['optionXX'];
}

//check if there is set an option and the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['option'])){

    //select the row which was selected, , maybe you need to change the column-name or/and table-name
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `optionXX` = '". $_POST['option'] . "'";
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
}
?>

<!-- change path test.php to your file name -->
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <select name="option">

    <?  foreach($optionsArray AS $option){ ?>

        <option value="<? echo $option; ?>"><? echo $option; ?></option>

    <? } ?>

    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?  
//when row is set 
if(isset($row)) {
    echo "Row " . $_POST['option'] . "<br><br>"; 

    //iterate over array $row
    foreach($row AS $key => $value){
        echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br>";
    }

}?>
```